# Problem with ESP32 and Wifi when powered by LiPo battery

Tags: voltage, esp32

I built a circuit around a ESP32 powered by a LiPo battery (I tested with 1800mAh and 4400mAh batteries), a MCP73871 to charge it and a TPRT9080 to regulate voltage.
When I use the ESP32 without Wifi, the circuit draw around 100mAh and I have no problem when the circuit is powered by the battery and when connected with USB.
When I try to add Wifi to the ESP32, the circuit draw around 200mAh when it start. I have no problem if the circuit is powered by USB but when powered by battery the ESP32 doesn't power up and I have the message "brownout detector triggered" and when I check with my multimeter, I have a big voltage drop at around 1.8V.
I can't understand why. Do you guys have an idea where the problem is ?
Here is the schematic of the circuit (I have omitted certain parts of the circuit but nothing that is used here)

[image: my circuit]

Comment: if that drop happens long enough to read with a dMM, you have too much electrical resistance between the battery and the ESP.  Maybe you have this on a crappy breadboard, or using cheap dupont jumper wires? Make sure your grounds are solid, not just the _OUT to the LDO.

Comment: The circuit is not on a breadboard but on a PCB and there is a ground plane on all the surface of the PCB. Can I measure the resistance between the battery and the ESP with my DMM ?